# How to use Virtual Channels with two RemoteApps located on two different Servers?

Tags: c++, plugins, rdp, virtual-channel

I made a 64 bits c++ [Virtual Channel Client DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383580.aspx)

I updated my registry, using [Virtual Channel Client Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383583.aspx) (I chose the `Default\Addins` way)

If I start a Remote Dekstop connection, everything goes fine: my DLL is loaded in a process named `mstsc.exe`, my exported `VirtualChannelEntry` callback is called, and, skipping details, I am able to send/receive bytes (with a little help from a process of my own, running in the server session, and which opens the Virtual Channel).

I am also able to open a second Remote Desktop connection to *another* Server. A second `mstsc.exe` process is started, it loads my DLL, all is OK.

My problems begin when I replace my two remote Desktops by two "RemoteApps" (one RemoteApp on the first Server, the other on the second Server).

When I launch the first RemoteApp, all is fine (a `mstsc.exe` starts, and load my DLL).

When I launch the second RemoteApp, there is NO new `mstsc.exe`, so no way for my DLL to be loaded again, but the existing `mstsc.exe` does NOT call my exported `VirtualChannelEntry`. I am not able to establish the Virtual Channel with the second Server.

The order does matter, not the RemoteApps. Only the *first* RemoteApp launched will give a Virtual Channel with its Server.

If I launch *only one* RemoteApp, and then launch a full Remote Desktop connection to the *other* Server, all is OK: two `mstsc.exe` loading my DLL, two Virtual Channel established.

Questions:

How to use Virtual Channels with two RemoteApps located on two different Servers?

Why is there only one `mstsc.exe` when I launch two RemoteApps, from two Servers, and why that single `mstsc.exe` does *not* call `VirtualChannelEntry` for the second connection?

My *client* OS is Windows 2012.
Problem reproduced with Windows 10 Pro as client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on Microsoft Technet. I reproduce it here, maybe helping future reader.

Add the following line to your RemoteApps RDP files:

```
disableconnectionsharing:i:1
```

Then, there will be one instance of `mstsc.exe` for each RemoteApps launched, and all of them will call your exported `VirtualChannelEntry` callback.

Beware, this an answer to the question asked, which states "two RemoteApps located on two **different** Servers".

The above configuration option *may* have some bad consequences if you are not in this case.

If you are an expert on that matter, feel free to improve this answer.